# React-Google-Maps DirectionsRenderer Panel

Tags: react-google-maps

When using the react-google-maps wrapper, does anyone know how to use "panel" as a prop in the directions renderer to display a panel that shows text instructions for a route that has been mapped.

https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer

Answer (score 4):

Was able to render a directions panel by setting props to:

```
(props =>
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={7}>
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions}
    panel={ document.getElementById('panel') } />}
    <div id="panel"></div>
  </GoogleMap>
);
```